# how to calculate numeric precision and other vals from atttypmod

Tags: postgresql, wal

I read the wal log from postgres (and that's all I have, can't access the tables of the database such as pg_attribute), and from relation event, I can get the atttypmod

is there a way for me to calculate the numeric precision and scale, and the chars length from that?

for chars, it seems that `atttypmod == col_length+4` , is that true?

for numeric precision, it seems more complex to calculate.
I created the following table based on [Where are NUMERIC precision and scale for a field found in the pg_catalog tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350148/where-are-numeric-precision-and-scale-for-a-field-found-in-the-pg-catalog-tables) , but I want to calculate these values only based on the atttypmod

| numeric_precision | numeric scale | atttypmod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 327686 |
| 5 | 1 | 327685 |
| 6 | 3 | 393223 |
| 4 | 4 | 262152 |

any ideas if / how I can do it only based on the atttypmod?

thanks, nizan

Comment: The function [format_type](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/format_type.c) converts a attypmod value to a readable string - maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

found that all we need is the attypmod and the type (numeric), so the code in java is

```
public int getNumericPrcision(int atttypmod, int atttypid){
    switch(atttypid){
      case 21:
        return 16;
      case 23:
        return 32;
      case 20:
        return 64;
      case 1700:
        if(atttypmod == -1)
          return -1;
        return  ((atttypmod - 4) >> 16) & 65535;
      case 700:
        return 24;
      case 701:
        return 53;
      default:
        return -1;
    }
  }

  public int getNumericScale(int atttypmod, int atttypid) {
    switch (atttypid) {
      case 20:
      case 21:
      case 23:
        return 0;
      case 1700:
        if(atttypmod == -1)
          return -1;
        return (atttypmod - 4) & 65535;
      default:
        return -1;

    }
  }
```